# Align textview in a block

Tags: android

I wat to create an app like this, I use textview to preview number

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/generatenumber1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generatenumber2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

How to align and color them like this, http://s24.postimg.org/sr53ezhtd/sdsd.png ?
I tried `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right` but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:gravity="center", and add padding to the left and right to create the whitespace between items.

Layout_gravity is used by layouts to define how they put the views inside it.  Gravity is used for text/data in a view.

Comment: Thanks, but how to color textview?

Comment: android:background=color and android:textColor for the text

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
```